# C#, event handler error with Serial Port

Tags: c#, delegates, event-handling, io

I am writing a data received event For Serial IO port...the following is the code

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;   //add namespaces
using System.IO.Ports;
     public class Program
        {

            //define a delegate class to handle DataReceived events
            internal delegate void SerialDataReceivedEventHanderDelegate(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e);

            internal void DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                //place code to read and process data here
            }

            static void Main()
            {

                string myComPortName=null;
                //1. find available COM port
                string[] nameArray = null;
                nameArray = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
                if(nameArray.GetUpperBound(0)>0) {
                myComPortName = nameArray[0];  
                }
                else {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error");
                    return;
                }    

                //2. create a serialport object
                // the port object is closed automatically by use using()
                SerialPort myComPort = new SerialPort();

                myComPort.PortName = myComPortName; //the default paramit are 9600,no parity,one stop bit, and no flow control

                   private static SerialDataReceivedEventHandler SerialDataReceivedEventHandler1 =
                   new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(ComPort.DataReceived);

                   myComPort.DataReceived+=SerialDataReceivedEventHandler1;


            }

        }
```

Why in VS2010, Line: 
private static SerialDataReceivedEventHandler SerialDataReceivedEventHandler1 = new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(ComPort.DataReceived);

is showing me:
1. invalid expression term 'private'
2. the modifier 'static' is not valid for this term
3. should I use Comport here? or just DataReceived...since its the function name

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Here is a good site to look at that will help you in terms of determining when and how to declare Access Modifiers and the what and what not is accessable / exposed | http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont need private static, just go :-

```
var SerialDataReceivedEventHandler1 =
                   new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(ComPort.DataReceived);
```

but if you are wanting that to be a member of the Program class, Move a declaration out to :-

```
   public class Program
        {

       private static SerialDataReceivedEventHandler;
```

then you need in Main

```
SerialDataReceivedEventHandler1 =
                       new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(ComPort.DataReceived);
```

but more likely, you really want to start your own class,  because "Program" isn't really the best place....  and dealing with static classes and static methods is a bit messy

Answer (score 2):

`private` and `static` are not valid in the scope of a method.
You can only declare static items at class level - i.e. here:

```
public class Program
{
   private static object _memberField;

   private static void MemberMethod()
   {
     // not here:
     // private static object _insideMethod; // <- will not work
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`private` is used to control the accessibility of members of a type, or types themselves. It is not applicable to a variable that is part of a method, since it's already most accessible to the method itself.

Additionally, the static modifier is not valid as well. It also applies to members of a type to indicate whether or not that member is instance aware.

Your line:

```
private static SerialDataReceivedEventHandler SerialDataReceivedEventHandler1 =  
               new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(ComPort.DataReceived);
```

Should be:

```
SerialDataReceivedEventHandler SerialDataReceivedEventHandler1 =  
               new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(ComPort.DataReceived);
```

However, that line seems entirely unnecessary in the first place. You could simplify it to:

```
myComPort.DataReceived += ComPort.DataReceived;
```

Answer (score 0):

That line is inside the main method. Private and static are only allowed outside of methods.

Answer (score 0):

private qualifier applies only for a member (member variables/methods) in your class definition. The SerialDataReceivedEventHandler is just a variable which you have inside a method.